# Bullet lists in sidenotes with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, floating, footnotes

I want to make a html document with sidenotes (margin notes). I found a solution to make a floating frame at the right side of the main text with a specific CSS class in a `<span>` flag. It works fine!

Now, I would like to include bullets lists in these side notes but then my bullet list appear in the main text and not in the sidenote. See below :

[image]

I also tried to display the span as a block but it didn't change anything.
Here his my HTML code for this example:

```css
body {
  margin-right: 400px
}

.sidenotes {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #558844;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  border: solid black 1pt;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent suscipit eros ut ullamcorper vestibulum.
  <span class="sidenotes" style="display:block;">aaaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aaaa
    aaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aa aa aa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaa </span> tempor, tempor tellus vel, feugiat tellus. Mauris facilisis eget felis ut mattis. Suspendisse nec .
  <p>
    <p>Donec accumsan,
      <span class="sidenotes" style="display:block;">bbbb b bb bbbb bbb bbb bbb bbb b
    <ul>
    <li><p >cccccc ccccccccc cccc</p></li>
    <li><p >ddd dddd ddd ddd ddd d</p></li>
    </ul></span> augue non pharetra imperdiet, nisi urna aliquam lorem, nec vulputate mi ipsum vel risus. Ut vel urna ut ipsum bibendum tempor ut id massa. Sed id ante risus. </p>
```

I tried using a `<div>` which give the correct result in the side note but not in the main text. The line is breaking at "Donec accumsan" (like the paragraph style):

```html
<p style="font-style:italic;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent suscipit 
eros ut ullamcorper vestibulum.
<span class="sidenotes">aaaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aaaa
aaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aa aa aa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaa</span> 
tempor, tempor tellus vel, feugiat tellus. Mauris facilisis eget felis 
ut mattis. Suspendisse nec .<p>
<p style="font-style:italic;">Donec accumsan, 
  <div class="sidenotes" ><p>bbbb b bb bbbb bbb bbb bbb bbb b</p>
    <ul>
      <li><p >cccccc ccccccccc cccc</p></li>
      <li><p >ddd dddd ddd ddd ddd d</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div> augue non pharetra imperdiet, nisi urna aliquam lorem, 
nec vulputate mi ipsum vel risus. Ut vel urna ut ipsum bibendum tempor ut 
id massa. Sed id ante risus.  </p>
```

which give:

[image]

**Do you have an idea how to modify my code to allow paragraphs, bullet lists and numbered lists in my sidenotes without breaking the line in the main text?**

**If not, is there another way to make side notes (margin notes)?**

Comment: <ul class="sidenotes">??

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `<span class="sidenotes" style="display:block;">` instead of, say, `<div class="sidenotes">`? `div` is always `display:block` unless modified...

Comment: In fact I made a previous test with <div class="sidenotes"> which break the line at "Donec accumsan". It the reason I tried <span> with block display.

Comment: A note on the `p` tag. It can only contain phrasing elements, this does not include `div` or `ul` tags. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p . If your `p` element contains `ul` or `div` (among others) the tag will be automatically closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to place your notes mid paragraph, let alone mid sentence. If you want to provide a semantic link between content in the paragraph and the side not, use and actual `a` link.

As I mentioned in a comment, you can not use `ul` or `div` mid `p` tag as you may only use phrasing content in a `p` tag. Using any other block level element will cause the `p` tag to close. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

I would go with placing the side notes after the paragraph they pertain to. Using the `:target` pseudo class we can add a high-lite to the appropriate footnote when the link is clicked

```css
.sidenotes  {float:right; clear:right; background-color:#CCFFCC; width: 200px;}
.sidenotes:target{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="sidenotes" id="sidenote-a">aaaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aaaa
aaa aaa aaa aa aaa aaa aa aa aa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaa</div> 
<p style="font-style:italic;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent suscipit 
eros ut ullamcorper <a href="#sidenote-a">vestibulum</a>.

tempor, tempor tellus vel, feugiat tellus. Mauris facilisis eget felis 
ut mattis. Suspendisse nec .<p>


 <div class="sidenotes" id="sidenote-b" ><p>bbbb b bb bbbb bbb bbb bbb bbb b</p>
    <ul>
      <li><p >cccccc ccccccccc cccc</p></li>
      <li><p >ddd dddd ddd ddd ddd d</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<p style="font-style:italic;">Donec <a href="#sidenote-b">accumsan</a>, 
  augue non pharetra imperdiet, nisi urna aliquam lorem, 
nec vulputate mi ipsum vel risus. Ut vel urna ut ipsum bibendum tempor ut 
id massa. Sed id ante risus.  </p>
```